# POST/GET in PHP

Tags: php, html, post, web, get

I have a simple html form

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <form action="trial2.html" method="get">
 <input type="text" name="name">
 <input type="submit">
 </form>
 </html>
```

which then runs this trial2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php
$val = $_GET["name"];
echo($val);
?>
</html>
```

I cannot work out why echo won't print out "name" although it can print out generic strings

I've been using w3schools as a reference but I think I'm just being stupid somewhere/completely missing the point.

Comment: Your file is .html instead of .php, I doubt you have set up PHP for .html files as it is quite inefficient.

Comment: is your server set to process php in html files? by default, it won't. try changing the extension and see what happens. Also, what will happen if `name` is empty?

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: Has anyone got a better website to use? (also I'll remove the link now)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `.html` file does not normally contain PHP code.

Rename your file to the `.php` extension and adjust your code to point to the renamed file, and change the `echo` to:

```
echo $val;
```

Comment: a .html file ***CAN*** contain PHP code, a lot do, but it won't be processed unless you configure your server to process the .html file extension.

Comment: well, you can always tell apache to process html files as php files, but that's beside the point...

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I renamed it .php but I still don't have any output from echo

Answer (score 0):

Most hosting companies don't enable embedded PHP in an html document.  So, save the file as `trial2.php` and upload it to your server.  The server will see the PHP extension and execute it.  HTML code in a PHP file is rendered as HTML.

Answer (score 0):

We can't run PHP in .html files because our server does not run it unless we tell it to run. To do this we need to create a **.htaccess** file in your root web directory and add this line to it:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
```

Otherwise simply change your file extention from  **.html** to **.php**